# Multiple instances of SFSpeechRecognizer?

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer

I am trying to run multiple instances of `SFSpeechRecognizer`. Unfortunately I always get this error:

`[Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"`

What does this error mean?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you understand the reason and/or find a solution?